# What to do when the NavMeshAgent is as close as it will get to the destination?

Tags: unity

If I determined the NavMeshAgent is as close to its destination as it's ever going to get, what do I do with it? Do I set the destination to the agent's current position? Do I set `isStopped` to true? Because it'll still be trying to get to that destination and I don't want it to keep trying.

Comment: Did you try [ResetPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.ResetPath.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a general problem whenever your agent tries to reach any destination, you should use the [`stoppingDistance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent-stoppingDistance.html) property of NavMeshAgent:

```
//Stop when we're 1 meter from our destination
navMeshAgent.stoppingDistance = 1;
```

If it's a situational issue, where you use your own code to determine that the agent can't get closer to a *specific* destination, you can use `navMeshAgent.isStopped = true` (don't forget to un-stop it later when it's given a new destination!) or `navMeshAgent.ResetPath()`.